# Very resource intensive Windows Phone 8 background task

Tags: c#, c++, background, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Would it be possible in any way if I could get the right permissions to run a very resource intensive task in the background on Windows Phone 8? My app needs to communicate with an external device over bluetooth, possibly for hours at end and send it instructions. These instructions are created from a large 3d model that would have to be loaded into memory. I would therefore require a few 100 megs of memory. I know the restrictions are max 10 minutes and 11mb of RAM.

Is there any way to do this?

PS. The RAM thing is possibly bypassable if I save the instructions to mass storage but will be a lot of effort.

Comment: if you put Sleep(ms) calls does the windows phone kernel/scheduler consider your app to be using consecutive 20minutes? as for the 11MB of ram where did you get that? Look at the documentation, you can get up to 380MB

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681682(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Memorylimitbyapptype

Comment: The RAM limit I get from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ConstraintsforallScheduledTaskTypes. That large is for an app, not a backround task.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not.

These restrictions are OS imposed restrictions and can't be bypassed.